# Average time between each transaction for customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I know the Average time between each transaction for customers (In seconds)?

```
 Time               Customer ID      Transaction
11/08/2020 00:00:01       1                 111
11/08/2020 00:02:00       2                  0
11/08/2020 00:02:07       1                  0
11/08/2020 00:03:09       3                  412
11/08/2020 00:04:00       1                  0
```

Before the Expected table I need to show the required steps:
for Customer ID 1 has 3 transactions ,  the differences transactions.

- the difference between first and second transaction  126 seconds.
- the difference between second and third transaction  113 seconds.

The Expected table:

```
Customer ID          Average time between each transactions for customer 
1                           (126+113)/3
2   
3
```

Comment: The average time *between* transactions should be `(126 + 113) / 2`, not `3`.

Answer (score 3):

The average time is the total time divided by one less than the number of transactions.  So:

```
select customerId,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then datediff(second, min(time), max(time)) / (count(*) - 1)
        end) as avg_time
from t
group by customerId;
```

Note:  SQL Server does integer division.  If you want a non-integer as a result, you might want a conversion or perhaps `count(*) - 1.0` in the expression.

This does assume that the times are only increasing (which seems like a reasonable assumption for this type of problem).

Comment: I think you have an error because you should be dividing by `count(*) - 1`.

Comment: @FDavidov . . . Actually, the OP has that issue.  I changed my answer and added a comment to that point.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your update just at the same time I pressed ENTER.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I think this query will only work for 2 records per customer...More than that it will not give correct output.Here, in this case, it will take only min and max for one id...what about other records in between min and max..we need to consider them as well..please correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: @vinaykoul . . . It will work.  You can try out some examples on paper, but for an increasing sequence, the average delay is the length (difference between the max and min) divided by one less than the number of points.